# Most efficient way to find order of magnitude of float in python

Tags: python, performance, loops, floating-point, processing-efficiency

I have to make some iterative calculation and I need to find the order of magnitude  (that bit after e in scientific notation) of my float number every time.
Currently I'm doing that with a loop, but it's eating up a lot of time and my calculations take forever.

```
while n<1.0:
    order=order-1
    n=n*10
```

Is there some function that I can use to just swiftly extract this info from the way python stores float numbers? 
I was taught that floating point numbers store the value and the exponent separately.

Edit: it's not a duplicate because I'm asking for the most efficient method. The one proposed with the logarithm is actually three times slower than the loop.

Comment: `math.floor(math.log10(n))`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839190/python-categorising-a-list-by-orders-of-magnitude

Comment: oh yes, I'm an idiot
thanks xq

Comment: actually, this just makes the code slower

Comment: I understand your grief about the speed issue not being addressed. However, it is a bit surprising that a single call to what is, hopefully, an optimized routine would be slower than a loop. This suggests there may be other issues involved, in which case providing a reproducible example so others could measure and investigate might help. Additionally, both methods are prone to floating-point rounding errors, so neither may truly return the mathematically correct magnitude. It could be useful to know whether that matters to your application, and why or why not.

Comment: (Additionally, Python may not be the best choice when speed is a requirement. A solution may be to use another language rather than to try to optimize Python code.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil I have to use python because it's a homework assignment. For the same reason, I'm a bit reluctant to show my code. Long story short, I have to calculate a probability and ridiculously small numbers appear so I remove the orders of magnitude before multiplying them again (I manually print out the correct order of magnitude with the end result). The loop presented above is nested in a bigger loop that iterates 10^10 times. It needs roughly an hour to calculate on my pc and I worry my professor just won't tolerate that kind of time.

Comment: In the bigger loop there is literally just one float division and one float multiplication, so I doubt that can be optimised in any way.

Comment: Your situation is an example of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your actual problem X is your attempted solution for the homework is too slow, but the question Y you asked about is faster calculation of the order of magnitude. There might be a better algorithm than you are using to solve the homework, one that does not encounter the tiny-number problem in the first place, or one might mitigate the tiny-number problem in a way other than calculating the order of magnitude. You should ask about the actual problem X.

Comment: @EricPostpischil ahaha, I'm pretty sure you're right!
I just want to divide two stupidly big numbers that are nowhere near the same order of magnitude, so I decided to split it into factors of more manageable fractions

Answer (score 20):

An easy way to do it would be to take the log of the number, and then floor the result of the log, like this:

```
import math
def orderOfMagnitude(number):
    return math.floor(math.log(number, 10))
```

Comment: actually, if I replace the loop with this, the whole code takes three times longer