# founding the precision of a float in python based on a different float number

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

So, let's say there is a float number: `0.11910000`

and here is a list of numbers: `11970, 12020, 12070, 12165, 12400, 11100`

I need them to turn to: `0.11970, 0.12020, 0.12070, etc...` this is based on the the the decimal point in the float number is `0.1191`, if it were `1.191` then the numbers would have been `1.197, 1.202, 1.207...`.
There is another point, that the decimal point should be where the number has the closest value to the original float. meaning:

if we take `9.21` as the original float number and have `944 968 1032` as the number, it should be `9.44, 9.68, 10.32` instead of `9.44, 9.68, 1.032`.

Now I have made a function after millions of tries, and my brain is so fried at this point the results are not even close. here is my embarrassing function:

```
def calculate_dec_place(num : float, original_num : float) -> float:
    return num / 10 ** len(str(int(round(num // original_num, -len(str(int(num // original_num))) + 1)))) - 1
```

Comment: What exactly is your question about this?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I guess my question is, how this can be implemented, or at least what math calculation can bring me to the wanted result?

Comment: Methinks this could be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52859751/most-efficient-way-to-find-order-of-magnitude-of-float-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need two functions, one of which finds the exponent of a number:

```
def find_exponent(n):
    return math.floor(math.log10(abs(n)))

find_exponent(0.01)  -2
find_exponent(0.1)   -1
find_exponent(1)      0
find_exponent(10)     1
find_exponent(100)    2
```

And another function that takes one number and shifts it so the exponent aligns:

```
def align_decimal(target: float, other: float) -> float:
    target_exponent = find_exponent(target)
    return other*10**(target_exponent - find_exponent(other))


Example math:
find_exponent(944)      = 2
find_exponent(0.000921) = -4
944*10^(-3 -(2))        = 0.000944

Example output:
align_decimal(0.000921, 944) 0.000944
```

We can now apply a list comprehension to get your answer:

```
def align_decimals(target: float, others: list[float]) -> list[float]:
    return [align_decimal(target, x) for x in others]

example:
align_decimals(9.21, [944, 968, 1032])
Out[50]: [9.44, 9.68, 1.032]

align_decimals(7.34, [0.101])
Out[51]: [1.01]
```

Full code:

```
import math


def find_exponent(n):
    return int(math.log10(abs(n)))


def align_decimal(target: float, other: float) -> float:
    target_exponent =
```

Comment: I tried: align_decimal(7.34, 0.101) and got 0.010100000000000001. I'm pretty sure the problem comes from find_exponent not ROUNDing the result.

Comment: With round instead of int, the result is 1.01 which is better, but still not quite right, the expected result being 10.1 .

Comment: Hmmm, round is not quite right either for the magnitude (your find_exponent), since the boundary between 2 magnitudes is log(5). Anyway, the find_exponent needs to be adjusted.

Comment: return math.ceil(math.log10(abs(n))-math.log10(5)) does it, except for the edge case 5, whose magnitude returns 0 instead of 1 (classical math rounding). If problematic, that can be solved with a test.

Comment: @Swifty Yep my answer had so many mistakes.... didnt even show the right results in my "example maths". I fixed my mistakes now (Just had to do math.floor)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fixed version of Tom McLeans' find_exponent function:

```
import math
def find_exponent(n):
    a = math.log10(abs(n))-math.log10(5)
    b = math.ceil(a)
    if a == b:
        return int(a+1)
    else:
        return b
```

Example cases:

```
find_exponent(0.0501)
Out[482]: -1

find_exponent(0.049999999999)
Out[483]: -2

find_exponent(78.1)
Out[484]: 2

find_exponent(500)
Out[485]: 3
```

Comment: Hmmm, now that I think about it, there's a flaw in my reasoning: a number between 1 and 10 must be rounded (in terms of order of magnitude) to 1 or 10, so the boundary between those 2 should be 5.5; or, if you reason multiplicatively, it would be sqrt(10) in which case rounding the log10 would be correct. That leaves for the OP to decide what they consider "the closest value" :) .